# How to speed up select distinct?

Tags: postgresql, performance, optimization, postgresql-9.3, amazon-rds, query-performance

I have a simple select distinct on some time series data:

```
SELECT DISTINCT user_id
FROM events
WHERE project_id = 6
AND time > '2015-01-11 8:00:00'
AND time < '2015-02-10 8:00:00';
```

And it takes 112 seconds. Here's the query plan:

http://explain.depesz.com/s/NTyA

My application has to preform a lot of distinct operations and counts like this. Is there a faster way to get this kind of data?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You probably don't want to hear this, but the best option to speed up `SELECT DISTINCT` is to **avoid** `DISTINCT` to begin with. In many cases (not all!) it can be avoided with better database-design or better queries.

Sometimes, `GROUP BY` is faster, because it takes a different code path.

In **your particular case**, it doesn't seem like you can get rid of `DISTINCT` (well, see below). But you can support the query with a special index if you have many queries of that kind:

```
CREATE INDEX foo ON events (project_id, "time", user_id);
```

In Postgres 11 or later, you can use an actual "covering" index like:

```
CREATE INDEX foo ON events (project_id, "time") INCLUDE (user_id);
```

Adding `user_id` is only useful if you get **index-only scans** out of this. See:

- https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/indexes-index-only-scans.html
- https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Index-only_scans

Would remove the expensive <strike>**Bitmap Heap Scan**</strike> from your query plan, which consumes 90% of the query time.

Your `EXPLAIN` shows 2,491 distinct users out of half a million qualifying rows. This won't become super-fast, no matter what you do, but it can be substantially faster. With around 200 rows per user, emulating an index skip scan on above index might pay. The range condition on `time` complicates matters, and 200 rows per user is still a moderate number. So not sure. See:

- [SELECT DISTINCT is slower than expected on my table in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66894500/939860)
- [Select first row in each GROUP BY group?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7630564/939860)
- [Optimize GROUP BY query to retrieve latest row per user](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25536748/939860)

Either way, if time intervals in your queries are always the same, a [**`MATERIALIZED VIEW`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-creatematerializedview.html) folding `user_id` per `(project_id, <fixed time interval>)` would go a long way. No chance there with varying time intervals, though. Maybe you could at least fold users per hour or some other minimum time unit, and that would buy enough performance to warrant the considerable overhead. Can be combined with either query style.

Nitpick:
Most probably, the predicates on `"time"` should really be:

```
AND "time" >= '2015-01-11 8:00:00'
AND "time" <  '2015-02-10 8:00:00';
```

Aside:
Don't use `time` as identifier. It's a [reserved word](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-keywords-appendix.html) in standard SQL and a basic type in Postgres.

Comment: I've read a bit about index only scans, I'll give it a shot.

Comment: Unfortunatly, the time interval is not fixed.

Comment: @Sam: So how much faster did your example query get with the suggested index?

Comment: @edwin: Haven't tried on production yet. However, I ran the original query on my local (with the same data) and it took 3678.780 ms. Then I added the index and it sped it up to 170.156 ms. Plan now contains 'Index Only Scan using foo on events'.

Comment: @Sam: Nice! That's what I was aiming for.

Comment: `but the best option to speed up SELECT DISTINCT is to avoid DISTINCT to begin with` this made me laugh and cry at the same time

Comment: Because of your answer, I learned about the existence of Materialized Views.

Comment: @Erwin wouldn't an index with `(project_id, "time") INCLUDE (user_id)` be a slight improvement space-wise over `(project_id, "time", user_id)`, now that Postgres has INCLUDE Indexes?

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ: Probably would. Like you say, only a slight improvement. This answer pre-dates the feature, but I updated now.

Comment: Erwin, can you take a look at a similar SELECT DISTINCT issue in Postgres which I posted on StackOverflow, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70869474/slow-postgres-query-with-a-select-distinct-and-a-join ? I'm also having trouble and was wondering if some simple indexes could fix it.

Answer (score 5):

Here's my test on Sam's case and [Erwin's answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/93159/22336)

```
drop table t1
create table t1 (id int, user_id int, project_id int, date_time timestamp without time zone) ;

insert into t1 -- 10 million row - size="498 MB"
select row_number() over(), round(row_number() over()/1000), round(row_number() over()/100000) , date
from generate_series('2015-01-01'::date, '2016-12-01'::date,'6 seconds'::interval
) date 
limit 10000000

-- before indexing - 10000000 row - output=100 row - time=2900ms
SELECT DISTINCT user_id
FROM t1
WHERE project_id = 1
AND date_time > '2015-01-01 8:00:00'
AND date_time < '2016-12-01 8:00:00' ;

CREATE INDEX foo ON t1 (project_id, date_time, user_id); -- time process=51.2 secs -- size="387 MB"         

-- after indexing - 10000000 row - output=100 row - time= 75ms (reduce ~ 38 times)
SELECT DISTINCT user_id
FROM t1
WHERE project_id = 1
AND date_time > '2015-01-01 00:00:00'
AND date_time < '2016-12-01 00:00:00' ;
```

Erwin said "You probably don't want to hear this, but the best option to speed up SELECT DISTINCT is to avoid DISTINCT to begin with. In many cases (not all!) it can be avoided with better database-design or better queries" . I think he's right, we should avoid using "distinct, group by, order by" (if any).

I met a situation as Sam's case and I think Sam can use partition on event table by month. It'll reduce your data size when you query, but you need a function (pl/pgsql) to execute instead of query above. The function will find appropriate partitions (depend on conditions) to execute query .

Comment: > I think he's right, we should avoid using "distinct, group by, order by" — and also SELECT, INSERT and UPDATE. If we avoid these constructs, our database will be very fast!

Answer (score 1):

You could try creating [a spatial index such as an "rtree" index](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/indexes-types.html) on all your columns `(time, project_id, user_id)`. I think this could speed up the query in theory, but I am not sure.

For others seeking speeding up `SELECT DISTINCT` without `WHERE`: Some database engines implement a special algorithm ("index skip scan", "loose indexscan", 
"jump scan") just to select distinct values from the leading columns of a b-tree index. PostgreSQL does not have it yet but has it on the roadmap as of 2020. See [Loose indexscan on the Postgres Wiki](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Loose_indexscan). It does not help in this particular case, because you have a range filter on another column, which also has to use the leading columns of a b-tree index. You have to choose only one.